# where is the implementation of method registerAsService() in Android HIDL

Tags: android, android-source, hidl

Where is the implementation of method `registerAsService()` in Android HIDL.

To register a service we are supposed to call this method.
But where is the implementation of this method?

Answer (score 1):

It is implemented in the generated code of your interface.

All it does is call `registerAsServiceInternal()` in `system/libhidl/transport/include/hidl/ServiceManagement.h`.

See [system/libhidl/transport/ServiceManagement.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/libhidl/+/refs/heads/android10-release/transport/ServiceManagement.cpp#829)